# How to write a MongoDB query that finds a field match from a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql

I'm trying to put together a MongoDB query that will return results where a field equals a value that is present in a JavaScript array. I've put together the following code so far but it isn't working. I would like the `number` field in the collection to find a match within the `versions` array. I'm thinking that my `"list"` part using the `$map` under the first `$project` is wrong.

```
//example data
var versions = ['v1', 'v2', 'v3'];

function getResults(versions) {

    var query =
    {
        "db": "db-name",
        "collection": "collection-name",
        "query":
        [
            {
                $match: {
                    time:  getStartTime(),
                }
            },
            {
                $project:
                {
                    number: "$number",
                    session_id: "$session_id",
                    round_id: "$_id",
                    "list": {
                        "$map": {
                            "input": { "$filter": {
                                "input": versions,
                                "as": "versions",
                                "cond": {
                                    "$eq": [ "$$versions.value", "$number" ]
                                }
                            }},
                            "as": "versions",
                            "in": "$$versions.value"
                        }
                    }

                }
            },
            {
                $group:
                {
                    _id: "$session_id",
                    number: { $first: "$list" },
                    rounds: { $addToSet: "$round_id" }
                }
            },
            {
                $project:
                {
                    number: "$number",
                    rounds: "$rounds"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    return query;
}
```

Comment: Can u provide sample input data and expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more info about you are triyng to do?

Maybe you can use **filter** by [javascript array](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro).

Here is an example code:

```
function isBigEnough(value) {
  return value >= 10;
}
var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(isBigEnough);
// filtered is [12, 130, 44]
```

Maybe **filter** could be useful for you.